# Light bounces differently in the viewport cycles render compared to the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, light, shadows

The view port render looks different to the final render. Any ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to click on "Show Emitter" under the Particle panel. That's what was causing the problem.